# Knockout's use of dollar sign in the html - any alternative?

Tags: knockout.js, silverstripe

Is there an alternative to using $data in Knockout.js?  I am using Silverstripe CMS with Knockout and upon refresh the browser looks for the variable 'data' on the server.  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there any way to escape the `$` so Silverstripe won't interpret it?

Answer (score 7):

Just escape it:

```
\$data
```

This is covered in [the escaping section of the template documentation](https://github.com/howardgrigg/sapphire/blob/master/docs/en/reference/templates.md#escaping).